# Locked myself out of an s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

By mistake I added a policy to an s3 bucket in us-east-1 region to restrict access only through traffic coming from a vpc in eu-west-1 region. I don't have access to root account. Us there's a way to remove this policy or delete the bucket with out root user?

Here's the policy:

```
  {
    "Sid": "Access-to-specific-VPC-only",
    "Principal": "*",
    "Action": "s3:*",
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Resource": "mybucket",
    "Condition": {
     "StringNotEquals": {
       "aws:SourceVpc": "eu-west-1 vpc id"
     }
    }
```

Comment: You have to contact who ever has the root access.

Comment: Please give more details, is that a bucket policy that you added? That shouldn't restrict AWS Console access or Management API Access in general. How are you exactly locked out?

Comment: Hi Augunrik - I added the bucket policy above. I can't view or modify anything in the bucket through aws console or API. I need to send traffic to the bucket to seem that it's coming from the eu-west-1 vpc, however i can't figure it out as private link is not supporting cross region. I'm looking for a work around if possible

Comment: How do you know the bucket policy if you don't have API/AWS Access? The bucket policy doesn't prevent API access and your question asks for bucket modification, not content modification. /// You should have a private link in the eu-west-1 VPC, otherwise it won't work (peering doesn't transport the origin vpc to my knowledge)

Comment: Yes i have a vpce in eu-west-1 however when i checked the documentation it turned out that vpce doesn't support cross region (traffic will travel through the internet to reach us-east-1) which the bucket will deny because of the source vpc not matching. I did had couple of tests to verify my understanding and it's correct.